# Exponential Expression Flex/Bison

Tags: compiler-construction, bison, flex-lexer, exponential

I am making a basic calculator in Flex/Bison and I want to do exponentials (^) but my current implementation is not working, can anyone tell me why not and how to fix it?

```
%{
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <math.h>
    void yyerror(char *);
    int yylex(void);
    int symbol;
%}

%token INTEGER VARIABLE
%left '+' '-' '*' '/' '^'

%%

program:
    program statement '\n'
    | /* NULL */
    ;
statement:
    expression          { printf("%d\n", $1); }
    | VARIABLE '=' expression   { symbol = $3; }
    ;
expression:
        INTEGER

    | VARIABLE          { $$ = symbol; }
    | '-' expression        { $$ = -$2; }
    | expression '+' expression { $$ = $1 + $3; }
    | expression '-' expression { $$ = $1 - $3; }
    | expression '*' expression { $$ = $1 * $3; }
    | expression '/' expression { $$ = $1 / $3; }
    | expression '^' expression { $$ = $1 ^ $3; }
    | '(' expression ')'        { $$ = $2; }
    ;

%%

void yyerror(char *s) {
    fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", s);
}
int main(void) {
    yyparse();
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Please watch your tagging; flex is used for the UI Framework; Flex-lexer is used for the lexical analyzer.

Comment: The exponentiation operator is right-associative, not left-associative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`^` is not the exponential operator in C; it's xor. You need to use the math library function `pow` or write your own integer exponentiation function.

Comment: Ok, now it's giving me a "undefined reference to pow", but i have included the <math.h>

Comment: I got it. Apparently you have to compile with the flag -lm. Is there any way around this other than making a makefile?

Comment: @Nelson.b.austin: You can remember to type -lm every time you compile, but the `make` utility was designed for this sort of thing, so I'd recommend it. Note that you don't actually need a makefile; you can just set the environment variable LDLIBS: `export LDLIBS=-lm`. Then the default `make` rules should work, although it might not be exactly how you want to build things. (If you need to compile your flex file as well, you'll need a real makefile, though.)

Answer (score 0):

I think this would work

```
 $$=pow($1,$3);
```

For more details, refer:    http://www-h.eng.cam.ac.uk/help/tpl/languages/flexbison/